# Why does the lithosphere thickness vary within a short distance?

Tags: geophysics, plate-tectonics, isostasy

Can someone explain why the lithosphere thickness varies within a short distance (30-100km) at the same upper mantle viscosity around the polar region?

And what is the behaviour of a thin (20-70km) versus a thick (100-160) lithosphere?

Comment: Please [edit] your text and add some numbers. What is *thick*, *thin* and *within a short distance*? Give a real world (observed) example if you have one.

Comment: What it your source for this information? And where exactly are you talking about - polar region is very vague.

Comment: Are you talking about crustal _type_ differences, as in Oceanic versus Continental settings or what?